# get list of parent records from a list of child records with joins or includes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

lets suppose I have to models

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
end

class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

and I have an array of kids

```
[k1, k2, k3, k4]
```

I want a list of parents of these kids something like

```
[p1, p2]
```

I want to do this with use of includes or joins any one can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it via Active Record:

```
Parent.joins(:kids).where("kids.id" => array_of_kids).pluck(:id)
```

Comment: can you help also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542188/convert-select-and-collect-methods-into-joins)