# convert select and collect methods into joins

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am learning joins I have three models

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bookings
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bookings
end

booking = Booking.first
booking.groups.collect{|g| g.users.select{|u| !self.users.include? u}}.flatten
```

I want to get all users which are not booked in booking groups some thing like this

```
booking=Booking.first
booking.groups.collect{|g| g.users.select{|u| !self.users.include? u}}.flatten
```

How can I do it with joins instead collect and select?

Comment: Try: `User.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN booking_users ON booking_users.user_id = users.id LEFT OUTER JOIN groups ON groups.user_id = users.id").joins(:group).where("booking_users.booking_id IS NULL")` or `User.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN booking_users ON booking_users.user_id = users.id LEFT OUTER JOIN bookings ON bookings.id = booking_users.booking_id").joins(:group).where("booking_users.booking_id IS NULL")`

Comment: Thanks for response but it did not work.

Comment: try: `User.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN groups ON groups.id = users.group_id LEFT OUTER JOIN booking_groups ON booking_groups.id = groups.id").where("booking_groups.id IS NULL")`

Comment: i've updated the answer, have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like (using [arel](/questions/tagged/arel) gem):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :non_booked_for, ->(booking_id) {
      users = User.arel_table
      bookings = Booking.arel_table
      groups = Group.arel_table
      where(groups_bookings[:booking_id].eq(booking_id)
       .and(groups_bookings[:group_id].eq(users[:group_id])))
       .not.where(user_bookings[:user_id].eq(users[:id])
             .and(user_bookings[:booking_id].eq(booking_id)))
   end
end
```

usage:

```
users = User.non_booked_for Booking.first.id
```

It just uses negation to all users, which belong to group and bookings, and its group belongs to that booking too. But I'm not sure that the negation will work properly here, so it should be debugged. And please select on of the two table names: `users_bookings`, or `bookings_users` for the associations, so, for example, in models it will lead to:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users

has_and_belongs_to_many :bookings, table_name: :users_bookings
```